# creating word search puzzle solver in c, Incompatible pointer type and pointer from integer without cast warnings in c

Tags: c, pointers

as the title says im attempting to create a program that searches through a 3x4 predefined grid for words that the user enters in the command line, i have the code completed but i am encountering these pointer warnings when i try to compile, the errors are as follow:

```
In function 'main':
59: warning: passing argument 1 of 'horizontalrow' makes pointer from integer without a cast
59: warning: passing argument 2 of 'horizontalrow' from incompatible pointer type
60: warning: passing argument 1 of 'verticalrow' from incompatible pointer type
60: warning: passing argument 2 of 'verticalrow' from incompatible pointer type
61: warning: passing argument 1 of 'diagonalrow' from incompatible pointer type
61: warning: passing argument 2 of 'diagonalrow' from incompatible pointer type
```

my code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define ROW 3
#define COL 4

void horizontalrow(char *a[ROW][COL], char *argv[], int argc)
{
  int i=0,j=0, k =0;
  for(i  = 0; i  < ROW - 1; i++){
    for(j = 0;j <  COL; j++){
      for(k=0;k<argc;k++){
    if(strcmp(a[i][j],argv[k])!=0){
      printf("%s appears horizontally at a[%d][%d]", a[i][j],i,j);

    }
    }
  }
  }
}

void verticalrow(char *a[ROW][COL], char *argv[], int argc)
{
  int i=0,j=0, k=0;
  for(j = 0; j< COL - 1; j++){
    for(i = 0; i < ROW; i++){
      for(k=0;k<argc;k++){
      if(strcmp(a[i][j], argv[k])!=0){
    printf("%s found veritcally at a[%d][%d]",a[i][j],i,j);
      }     
     }
    }
  }

}

void diagonalrow(char *a[ROW][COL], char *argv[], int argc)
{
  int slice = 0, i = 0, j =0, z1 = 0, z2 =0, k=0;
  for(slice = 0; slice < ROW + COL -1; slice++){
    for(j = z2; j <= slice - z2; j++){
      for(k=0;k<argc;k++){
      if(strcmp(a[i][j],argv[k])!=0){
    printf("%s is found diagonally at a[%d][%d]", a[i][j], i, j);
      }     
 }
    }
  }

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i=0,j=0,k=0;
  char a[ROW][COL] ={ {'a','b','c','d'},
              {'d','c','b','a'},
              {'x','y','z','d'}};

  horizontalrow(a[ROW][COL],argv[k], argc);
  verticalrow(a[ROW],argv[k], argc);
  diagonalrow(a[ROW],argv[k], argc);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you don't understand the basic of using arrays in C. This page might be helpful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array.

Comment: whozcraig, are you saying i get rid of the row vector when declaring in the functions? and where are you telling me to call argc, argv, and a at? i thought i was doing that in the main

Comment: R Sahu, can elaborate, it would be nice to have some specifics

Comment: A `char` is a form of integer in C.`char *a[ROW][COL]` is a pointer and `a[ROW][COL]` at the time of use in `main` is `char`. So resolve warnings to get your code correct and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many errors in your code. Here's a working program to get you going in the right direction. I have removed `verticalrow` and `diagonalrow` to simplify things.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROW 3
#define COL 4

void horizontalrow(char a[ROW][COL], char *argv[], int argc)
{
   int i=0,j=0, k =0;
   for(i  = 0; i  < ROW - 1; i++)
   {
      for(j = 0;j <  COL; j++)
      {
         for(k=0;k<argc;k++)
         {
            if(a[i][j] == *argv[k] )
            {
               printf("%c appears horizontally at a[%d][%d]\n", a[i][j], i, j);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char a[ROW][COL] = { {'a','b','c','d'},
                       {'d','c','b','a'},
                       {'x','y','z','d'} };

  horizontalrow(a, argv+1, argc-1);

  return 0;
}
```

**Changes made to your program**

1. Signature of the function.

   You had:

   ```
   void horizontalrow(char *a[ROW][COL], char *argv[], int argc)
   ```

   I changed it to

   ```
   void horizontalrow(char a[ROW][COL], char *argv[], int argc)
                       //  ^^^ no pointer, just the array.
   ```

   You declaration expects the argument to be a two dimensional array of pointers to `char`. What you need is just a two dimensional array `char`s.
2. Comparing the command line arguments.

   You had:

   ```
   if(strcmp(a[i][j],argv[k])!=0){
   ```

   I changed it to:

   ```
   if(a[i][j] == *argv[k] )
   ```

   Your code was syntactically correct but didn't make any sense semantically. My changes assume that the command line arguments you use  to run the program are single character strings, such as

   ```
   myprogram a b c
   ```

   If you had a different idea for the command line arguments, you'll need to adapt the code.
3. Format specifier in `printf`.

   You had:

   ```
   printf("%s appears horizontally at a[%d][%d]", a[i][j],i,j);
   ```

   I changed it to:

   ```
   printf("%c appears horizontally at a[%d][%d]\n", a[i][j], i, j);
   ```

   You had a syntactically valid format specifier. Since I changed the argument type, I had to change the format specifier too.
4. Removed unnecessary variables from `main`.

   I removed the line

   ```
   int i=0,j=0,k=0;
   ```

   You don't need these variables.
5. Changed the syntax used to call the function.

   You had:

   ```
   horizontalrow(a[ROW][COL],argv[k], argc);
   ```

   I changed it to:

   ```
   horizontalrow(a, argv+1, argc-1);
   ```

   Use of `a[ROW][COL]` as an argument calls the function by using the value obtained from evaluating `a[ROW][COL]`. It is syntactically wrong. The expected type of the function does not match the value type. The value type is `char`. Also, evaluation of `a[ROW][COL]` leads to undefined behavior since you are accessing the array out of bounds. The valid range of indices to access `a` are `a[0][0]` through `a[ROW-1][COL-1]`.

   It's not clear to me what you were hoping to pass to the function by using `argv[k]`. The value type of `argv[k]` does not match the argument type of the function. You can read more about using command line arguments at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function. Hopefully when you have finished reading that page, you will understand why I am using `argc-1` as the third argument to `horizontalrow`.

Comment: ok thank you very much for your time, i will review this and look over my code



as to your question about why i use argv[k], i thought that is what i have to use to compare the two arrays at that index, 


but i see now that i have to study this stuff further as i do not comprehend it as well as i thought did


also in regards to this comment 


My changes assume that the command line arguments you use to run the program are single character strings, such as


myprogram a b c,


you are correct, the user is to enter myprog xyz bdc efg to be searched

Comment: my god that comment i just left is horribly formatted, im sorry for your eyes. At the end i wanted to verify that you are correct that the input comes from myprog abc xyz edf on the command line but not single characters, rather a string, instead of a b c it is abc. So this problem isnt so much involving string as it is just singular characters?

Comment: When the command line used is `myprogram abc xyz def`, is the string `"abc"` expected to be passed to `horizontalrow`? I am guessing yes. In that case, you'll need to change the signature of `horizontalrow`, the code that does the check against `a[i][j]` and the function call.

Comment: yes, all three of those strings are to be passed to the functions and searched for, this is why i was attempting to use the string compare command. when you say the signature of horizontalrow, what line are you referring to? the print statement?